# Can you die from severing your penis?

Tags: blood, death, suicide

I recently saw a very disturbing post history on Reddit about a person with the stump of a penis left, and no testicles, as he severed his penis by shooting it off and castrated himself.

He said he planned on committing suicide last weekend by shooting off the remaining stump with his revolver, and we haven’t heard from him since.

Can you really die or bleed to death from a small wound such as removing the stump of a penis?

Comment: I suggest you don't do this!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do you bleed to death after your penis is cut off?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/1258/do-you-bleed-to-death-after-your-penis-is-cut-off)

Comment: I retracted my close vote because the duplicate question didn't involve firearms. Cutting a penis and testicles off with a knife is unlikely to kill you, but a gunshot aimed a mere centimeter too high could easily do so.

Comment: @CareyGregory Furthermore, dealing with blood loss is one hint. Dealing with deadly infections and other problems arising from such an open wound is a totally different level. I’d say that - especially with a firearm - this is very potentially deadly, and a lot more than severing it with a knife.